# How do I run a thread run() inside of the GUI's actionPerformed() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, interrupt-handling

This is my first time doing multi-threading and I'm kind of stuck on how to make two threads, "Reader" thread and "Writer" thread execute only when the JButton "jbStart" is clicked? I can't put the run() method inside of the actionPerformed() because it won't run right, neither can I add thread.start() inside of it, it has to be in a static main method, unless I'm wrong correct me. Right now, the entire code functions as is. For further insight, it is simply a Target Finder program, where you put in the Max # (the max number of random numbers to be generated - For ex: Max # = 100, random numbers will generate anywhere between 0 - 100), Target # (the target number to be found and how long it took in ms.) Buffer just reads the JTextArea.

"Reader" Thread
-reader stops when found target # and display time correctly.

"Writer" Thread
-writer generates random numbers using max #.

My real question is how do I blend the two threads with this and I already tried adding sleep, interrupt, notify, signalAll, etc..., but i just don't know where to put it to make it work properly. Hopefully, you guys could show me how that would work in this program and I can gladly learn from it and have the acquired knowledge of how threads work. here's the code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class TargetFinder extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
//GUI attributes
JLabel jlMax, jlTarget, jlBuffer;
JTextField jtfMax, jtfTarget, jtfBuffer;
JTextArea txtArea;
JScrollPane jsp;
JButton jbStart, jbReset, jbExit;
JPanel pnl1, pnl2, nPnl, sPnl;
int isIntegerMax, isIntegerTarget;
String isStringMax, isStringTarget;

public TargetFinder()
{
  //create frame
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  //create content
  /*-------------------------------NORTH-------------------------------*/

  jlMax = new JLabel("Max #");
  jtfMax = new JTextField(7);

  jlTarget = new JLabel("Target #");
  jtfTarget = new JTextField(7);

  jlBuffer = new JLabel("Buffer");
  jtfBuffer = new JTextField(7);
  jtfBuffer.setEditable(false);

  //create panel and add contents to it
  pnl1 = new JPanel();
  pnl1.add(jlMax);
  pnl1.add(jtfMax);
  pnl1.add(jlTarget);
  pnl1.add(jtfTarget);
  pnl1.add(jlBuffer);
  pnl1.add(jtfBuffer);

  nPnl = new JPanel();
  nPnl.add(pnl1);

  add(nPnl,"North"); //add the panel to the North on the JFrame

  /*-------------------------------CENTER-------------------------------*/

  txtArea = new JTextArea(25,60);
  txtArea.setLineWrap(true);
  txtArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
  txtArea.setEditable(true);
  jsp = new JScrollPane(txtArea);
  jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

  add(jsp,"Center"); //add JScrollPane to the JTextArea where as-is

  /*-------------------------------SOUTH-------------------------------*/

  jbStart = new JButton("Start");
  jbStart.setMnemonic('S');

  jbReset = new JButton("Reset");
  jbReset.setMnemonic('R');

  jbExit = new JButton("Exit");
  jbExit.setMnemonic('x');

  //create panel and add contents to it
  pnl2 = new JPanel();
  pnl2.add(jbStart);
  pnl2.add(jbReset);
  pnl2.add(jbExit);

  sPnl = new JPanel();
  sPnl.add(pnl2);

  add(sPnl, "South"); //add the panel to the South on the JFrame

  //ActionListener Registration
  //jtfMax.addActionListener(this);
  //jtfTarget.addActionListener(this);
  //jtfBuffer.addActionListener(this);
  jbStart.addActionListener(this);
  jbReset.addActionListener(this);
  jbExit.addActionListener(this);

  //GUI properties
  setTitle("Target Finder");
  setLocation(200,200);
  setSize(700,500);
  setVisible(true);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  pack(); //resize window to fit
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
  //checks user input of jtfMax and jtfTarget
  if(ae.getSource() == jbStart)
  {
     /*------------------------MAX #------------------------*/
     try
     {
        isStringMax = jtfMax.getText(); //get the text of Max #
        isIntegerMax = 0;

        isIntegerMax = Integer.parseInt(isStringMax); //convert from String to int

        if(isIntegerMax < 0) //if the value is negative
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a positive number", "Max #", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
     {
        if(jtfMax.getText().isEmpty())
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a positive number", "Max #", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You entered: " + isStringMax + "\nPlease enter a positive number", 
           "Max #", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
     }

     /*------------------------TARGET #------------------------*/
     try
     {
        isStringTarget = jtfTarget.getText(); //get the text of Target #
        isIntegerTarget = 0;

        isIntegerTarget = Integer.parseInt(isStringTarget); //convert from String to int

        if(isIntegerTarget < 0) //if the value is negative
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a positive number", 
           "Target #", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
     {
        if(jtfTarget.getText().isEmpty())
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a positive number", "Target #", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You entered: " + isStringTarget + "\nPlease enter a positive number", 
           "Target #", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
     }

     try
     {
        if(isIntegerTarget >= isIntegerMax || isIntegerTarget < 0) //if Target # >= Max # (>= avoids a glitch where it freezes the program if Max # = Target #)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a target number < Max #");
        }
        else
        {
           //checks both values if can be converted to an int
           Integer.parseInt(isStringMax);
           Integer.parseInt(isStringTarget);

           try
           {
              Random randomGenerator = new Random(); //create a random object for random numbers
              Boolean foundMatch = false; //check when random numbers = Target #

              final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //start of the program's execution time in milliseconds
              //generates many random numbers until condition is met
              while(!foundMatch)
              {
                 int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(isIntegerMax); //generates random numbers up to the value of Max # (isIntegerMax)
                 String isStringRandom = Integer.toString(randomInt); //convert random numbers to String
                 txtArea.append(randomInt + " "); //add random numbers to the JTextArea

                 String isBuffer = Integer.toString(randomInt); //convert randomInt int to String
                 jtfBuffer.setText(isBuffer);

                 String isStringTarget = Integer.toString(isIntegerTarget); //convert Target # (isIntegerTarget) to String

                 //if the Buffer matches the Target #
                 if(isBuffer.equals(isStringTarget))
                 {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    break;
                 }
              }
              final long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; //calculate the total time of the program's execution
              txtArea.append("\nIt took " + duration + " milliseconds");
              txtArea.requestFocus();
           }
           catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
           {
              iae.printStackTrace(); //prints the error messages
              return;
           }
        }
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Either Max # and/or Target # is not a number. Please enter a positive number");
     }
  }
  else if(ae.getSource() == jbReset)
  {
     //empty all text fields
     jtfMax.setText("");
     jtfTarget.setText("");
     jtfBuffer.setText("");
     txtArea.setText("");
     jtfMax.requestFocus();
  }
  else if(ae.getSource() == jbExit)
  {
     System.exit(0);
  }
}

/**
  This class implements the first runnable object for the first thread
*/
class Runnable1 implements Runnable
{
  public synchronized void run()
  {
     try
     {
        Thread.sleep(1);
     }
     catch(InterruptedException ie)
     {
        System.out.println("Reader Thread #1 Interrupted!");
     }
  }
}

/**
  This class implements the second runnable object for the second thread
*/
class Runnable2 implements Runnable
{
  public synchronized void run()
  {
     try
     {
        Thread.sleep(1);
         /*------------------------BUFFER------------------------*/

        //String isBuffer = Integer.toString(isIntegerTarget); //convert Target # int to String
        //jtfBuffer.setText(isBuffer);

        /*------------------------RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR------------------------*/

        /*READER THREAD HANDLES THIS*/

        /*WRITER THREAD HANDLES THIS*/


        /*
        try
        {
           if(isIntegerTarget >= isIntegerMax) //if Target # >= Max # (>= avoids a glitch where it freezes the program if Max # = Target #)
           {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a target number < Max #");
           }
           else
           {
              //checks both values if can be converted to an int
              Integer.parseInt(isStringMax);
              Integer.parseInt(isStringTarget);

              try
              {
                 Random randomGenerator = new Random(); //create a random object for random numbers
                 Boolean foundMatch = false; //check when random numbers = Target #

                 final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //start of the program's execution time in milliseconds
                 //generates many random numbers until condition is met
                 while(!foundMatch)
                 {
                    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(isIntegerMax); //generates random numbers up to the value of Max # (isIntegerMax)
                    String isStringRandom = Integer.toString(randomInt); //convert random numbers to String
                    txtArea.append(randomInt + " "); //add random numbers to the JTextArea

                    String isBuffer = Integer.toString(randomInt); //convert randomInt int to String
                    jtfBuffer.setText(isBuffer);

                    String isStringTarget = Integer.toString(isIntegerTarget); //convert Target # (isIntegerTarget) to String

                    //if the Buffer matches the Target #
                    if(isBuffer.equals(isStringTarget))
                    {
                       foundMatch = true;
                       break;
                    }
                 }
                 final long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; //calculate the total time of the program's execution
                 txtArea.append("\nIt took " + duration + " milliseconds");
                 txtArea.requestFocus();
              }
              catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
              {
                 iae.printStackTrace(); //prints the error messages
                 return;
              }
           }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Either Max # and/or Target # is not a number. Please enter a positive number");
        }
        */

     }
     catch(InterruptedException ie)
     {
        System.out.println("Writer Thread #2 Interrupted!");
     }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
  {
     @Override
     public void run() 
     {
        // create the window
        TargetFinder targetFinder = new TargetFinder(); //runs the program

        // create the writer thread
        Runnable r1 = targetFinder.new Runnable1();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);

        // create the reader thread
        Runnable r2 = targetFinder.new Runnable2();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);


        // start the threads
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        /*try
        {
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
           ie.printStackTrace();
           return;
        }*/
     }
   });
}
}
```

Comment: There's a good place to read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). If you already read that, it will help you a lot to minimize an example for showing your problem.

Comment: SSCCE please, we don't do homeworks here..

Answer (score 2):

> This is my first time doing multi-threading and I'm kind of stuck on how to make two threads, "Reader" thread and "Writer" thread execute only when the JButton "jbStart" is clicked?

So why did you write a 300 line program to test this?

Why don't you start with a GUI that contains a single JButton called "Start" that starts a Thread when it is clicked. Once you get that working, then you make changes to your real program.

This is called creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Then if it still doesn't work you have simple code to post on the forum. We don't have time to read through all your code to see what you are doing.

> I can't put the run() method inside of the actionPerformed() because it won't run right

What does doesn't run right mean? If it doesn't work then you didn't implement the Thread correctly. We don't know what you are attempting to do so we can't give specific advice.

> neither can I add thread.start() inside of it, it has to be in a static main method, unless I'm wrong correct me

You should not be using static methods. Just create your Runnable as a class variable. Then you can invoke the start() method from anywhere in your class. Or define the whole Runnable in the actionPerformed() method.

Comment: It's a homework assignment I'm doing and have to add threads to it, that's why!

Comment: Did you read my answer??? Start with something simple until you understand what you are doing. Then add the code back into your real assignment. Learn to walk before you run!